# Compilation error in Include file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file, compilation, include

I'm working on my company's website. The task I have is to display the user's name and ID at the top of each page of the website, once the user logs in. However, the top section of each page is controlled by an Include file, Header.inc. I'm getting the examinee's name and ID through some VB/Javascript. The problem is that an aspx page inserts the Include file before it runs the VB/javascript (if you're not familiar with what I'm talking about, see here, towards the bottom of the page: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_incfiles.asp). Basically, the code in the Include file references the variables for the name and ID before the script declares them. The only solution I currently know would be to get rid of the Include file and insert that html in each page, but I'd like to avoid that. Any ideas how I can get around this problem? I read that Include files are old school and I should use Master files instead, but I really don't know how to do that. I'm pretty new at aspx development and working on modifying an existing website I did not create. Please be as specific as possible in your answers.

Thanks in advance,
Dan

**Here's the error I get on the webpage:**
(FYI the webpage is index.aspx)

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: BC30451: Name 'strName' is not declared.

Source Error:


Line 11:          </br>
Line 12:          </br>
Line 13:          <a><%=strName%>&nbsp; </a>
Line 14:          </br>

Line 15:         <a>Examinee ID# <%=strNBCEID%>&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>
```

**Here's the code for the Include file:**
(the include file is Header.inc)

```
        <!-- Start Header -->

    <div class="container-header">
        <div class="pageheader">
            <a href="/home.aspx" > (text removed) Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="(link removed)" >(text removed)</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="/logout.aspx" >Logout</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="/contact.aspx" >Contact Us</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
     </br>
     </br>
     </br>
     </br>
     <a><%=strName%>&nbsp; </a>
     </br>
    <a>Examinee ID# <%=strNBCEID%>&nbsp;&nbsp; </a> 
    </div>

        <div class="header">
            <br />
            <span id="menuiconspan">
                <a onclick="showMenu()">
                    &nbsp;<img src="/images/menubutton.png" />
                </a>
            </span>
            <span id="headermenulogospan-lg" >
                <img src="/images/logow.png" height="73px" width="187.5" />
            </span>&nbsp; 
            <span id="headermenulogospan-sm">
                <img src="/images/logow.png" height="49px" width="125" />
            </span>&nbsp; 
        </div>            
    </div>

    <!-- End Header -->
```

**Here's some of the code (the section I deemed relevant) of my aspx file:**
(webpage name is index.aspx, just for reference)

```
    <%@ Page Language="VB" Inherits="MySecurity" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">
    Dim strName As String
    Dim strAddress As String
    Dim strPhone As String
    Dim strEmailProc as String
    dim strNBCEID as String

    Protected Sub Page_Load()
        Dim dvUser As Data.DataView

        SecurityCheck()

        sqlUser.SelectParameters("ExamineeNo").DefaultValue = Session("ExamineeNo")
        dvUser = sqlUser.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
        strName = dvUser.Table.Rows(0)("FirstName").ToString & " " & dvUser.Table.Rows(0)("LastName").ToString & " " & dvUser.Table.Rows(0)("Suffix").ToString
        If dvUser.Table.Rows(0)("CurrentCountry").ToString = "1" Then
            strAddress = dvUser.Table.Rows(0)("CurrentStreet").ToString & "<br />" & dvUser.Table.Rows(0)("CurrentCity").ToString & ", " & dvUser.Table.Rows(0)("CurrentState").ToString & " " & dvUser.Table.Rows(0)("CurrentZip").ToString
        Else
            strAddress = dvUser.Table.Rows(0)("CurrentStreet").ToString & "<br />" & dvUser.Table.Rows(0)("CurrentCity").ToString & " " & ZipFormat(dvUser.Table.Rows(0)("CurrentCountry").ToString, dvUser.Table.Rows(0)("CurrentZip").ToString) & "<br/>" & GetTableValueString("lkpCountry", "CountryName", "[CountryID]=" & dvUser.Table.Rows(0)("CurrentCountry").ToString)
        End If
        If dvUser.Table.Rows(0)("CurrentPhone").ToString <> "" Then
            strPhone = Left(dvUser.Table.Rows(0)("CurrentPhone").ToString, 3) & "-" & Mid(dvUser.Table.Rows(0)("CurrentPhone").ToString, 4, 3) & "-" & Right(dvUser.Table.Rows(0)("CurrentPhone").ToString, 4)
        Else
            strPhone = ""
        End If
        strEmailProc = dvUser.Table.Rows(0)("Email").ToString
        strNBCEID = dvUser.Table.Rows(0)("NBCEID").ToString

    End Sub
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>(text removed)</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/template.js"></script>
    <link href="../css/template.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function PageLoad() {

        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="PageLoad()" onresize="resetMenu();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" requiressl="true">
        <div>
            <!-- #include virtual="~/include/sidenav.inc" -->
            <!-- #include virtual="~/include/header.inc" -->
            <div class="container">
                <!-- #include virtual="~/include/leftcolumn.inc" -->
```

Thanks again

Comment: Can you post the name of each file...and also which file includes the other?

Comment: @Hackerman
Hi. I have now named them in my original post. The include file is Header.inc. The name of the webpage is index.aspx. Hope that helps. Thanks